# Performing 2 successive tasks when a HTML form is submitted (using Ajax and a server made with Express in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, forms

I have an input form in a HTML file:

```
<form id="urlarticle">
      <input type='text' name='thislink'>
      <input type='submit' value='Select'>
</form>
```

I want, when the submit button is clicked, 2 things to happen, in this order:

TASK 1: Make a POST request to a server, in order to enter new data in a database. Actually it is already working with the following code on the front-end:

```
<script type='application/javascript'>
        $("#urlarticle").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/selection/yes",
            data: $("#urlarticle").serialize(), 
            success: function(data)
            {alert(data); 
            }
        });
        return false; 
      });     
</script>
```

...and with the following code on the back-end (server made with Express in Node.js):

```
app.post('/selection/yes', function(req, res) {
  link = req.body.thislink;  
  // part omitted here: function that do several things and then save some data to a database
});
```

TASK 2: Open a new window, rendered with an EJS view following a GET request on the server-side. TASK 2 has to be performed after TASK 1, because it uses the data saved in the database by TASK 1.

The code on the front-end should look like this:

```
<script type='application/javascript'>
    $("#urlarticle").submit(function() {
    var linkValue = $('input[name="thislink"]').val();
    window.open('/selection/yes/?value='+linkValue);
    });
</script>
```

...and the task is ready to be handled on the back-end:

```
app.get('/selection/yes/', function(req, res) {
    var thislink = req.param("value");
    // parts omitted here
    res.render('selection_form.ejs'); 
    });
});
```

But how can I make this TASK 2 to be executed only after TASK 1 is done? Thank you for your help!

Comment: An async control flow library will help with the first question. For example, using [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) allows promises to be used to chain the sequences together. I'm not sure what your second question means though, I can't follow what `thislink` stands for.

Comment: I'll have a look at Bluebird, thanks. Regarding the second question, it was a bit confusing, so I edited the post, and in fact there is not any second question _per se_ anymore.

Comment: Ok great, let me take a look and give a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a sample NodeJS application that uses a lot of the same concepts (using Express and some jQuery on the client-side).

**WORKING EXAMPLE:** http://runnable.com/U3JEKcrGzPc1V8eQ/promises-w-bluebird-for-node-js-and-express

Using a basic Express application where an initial form is rendered using `EJS` (this is the `GET` request on `/`). Form submissions return a `POST` request to the same URL and are handled with a 2s delay to simulate a database action.

```js
/**
 * Create a global storage variable as a example of an 
 * attached local database
 */
GLOBAL.linkStorage = [];

app.route('/')
  .post(function(req, res){
    console.log("Submission: " + req.body);
    GLOBAL.linkStorage.push(req.body.link);
    renderDelayedResponse(res);
  })
  .get(function(req, res){
    res.render('form.ejs');
  });

app.route('/2')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    // No need to pass in GLOBAL.linkValue since it's checked automatically
    res.render('submission.ejs');
  });

/**
 * Delay the response by a few seconds to simulate a database
 * create/update action
 */
function renderDelayedResponse(respWriter) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    GLOBAL.viewCount++;
    respWriter.send('Action Completed');
  }, 2000);  
}
```

There are going to be problems with calling `window.open()` *after* an asynchronous action, the popup blocker fires in all cases through my tests. To workaround this, you can see that the example has an embedded `IFRAME` that refreshes (after the 2 second database save completes) and displays the submitted value.

The complexity is mostly handled through jQuery where the `IFRAME` refresh occurs *after* we know that the `POST` request has submitted:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .busy {
        cursor: wait !important;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('document').ready(function () {

        function refreshViewer() {
          window.open("/2", "viewer");
          document.getElementById('submissionFrame').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        }

        $('form input#submitLink').on('click', function () {
          var linkValue = $('input#link').serialize();
          $('body').addClass('busy');
          $.post('/', linkValue)
            .done(function(data) {              
              $('body').removeClass('busy');
              $('input#link').val('');
              refreshViewer();
            });           
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="urlarticle" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Link" id="link" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitLink" />
      </form>

      <iframe id="submissionFrame" src="/2" seamless="seamless" width="50%" style="margin-top:100px">

      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like the runnable code has a superfluous require('bluebird')?  It's ranked pretty high as a bluebird search in google (for me), and it appears to be unrelated?

Comment: @jimm101 You're right, I had reused an older Runnable to answer this question. I'll update...